# What is the equivalent of uint8_t in swift?

Tags: c++, objective-c, swift, type-conversion

There's a method in an obj-c/c++ framework that takes a **uint8_t** and a regular **int**:

```
- (bool)push:(uint8_t *)buf length:(int)len;
```

I used a bridger file to have access to this method, but when I call it in swift using **UInt8** and **Int** I get the following error:

*Cannot invoke 'push' with an argument list of type '(UInt8, length: Int)'*

How can I make it work?

Answer (score 5):

The method expects a pointer to an array of elements of `UInt8` type and an `Int32` value. You can do something like this:

```
var buffer: [UInt8] = [0, 1, 2]
yourObject.push(UnsafeMutablePointer<UInt8>(buffer), length: Int32(buffer.count))
```

Check out here how pointers should be handled: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/BuildingCocoaApps/InteractingWithCAPIs.html